# Use Excel to Export clipboard function

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

I try to replace the 'Export to Excel' function with a 'Export to OpenOffice' function.
Pasting data of the clipboard to OpenOffice already works. I would like to use the code of the 'Export to Excel' function which copies the grid data to the clipboard (kernel side). So is there any way to call that function or a workaround?

It is also no option to modify `SysGridExportToExcel` because the Export to Excel Button which copies the grid data to the clipboard and then proceeds to call `performPushAndFormatting` is deactivated if there is no Excel installed (also kernel side).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the class `SysGridExportToExcel`
There is a method `performPushAndFormatting` which is called during the export and performs the data transfer to Excel.

Comment: I already checked this class/method and it is called after the clipboard is filled. I just edited my question for more information.